# Как закончить программу?

Tags: python

```
import random

words_list = ('автострада', 'бензин', 'инопланетянин', 'самолет',
             'библиотека', 'шайба', 'олимпиада', 'весна')

secret_word = random.choice(words_list)
print(secret_word)

gamer_word = ['*'] * len(secret_word)
print(''.join(gamer_word))

errors_counter = 0
while True:
   letter = input('введите ОДНУ русскую букву: ').lower()
   if len(letter) != 1:
       continue

   if letter in secret_word:
       for idx, symbol in enumerate(secret_word):
           # print(idx, symbol)
           if symbol == letter:
               gamer_word[idx] = symbol
   else:
       errors_counter += 1
       print('ошибок допущено', errors_counter)
       if errors_counter == 8:
           print('вы проиграли ;(')
           break

   print(''.join(gamer_word))
```

при написании восьми неверных букв код работает верно и выходит из программы. Но при написании полного слова предоставленного в массиве не завершается.

Comment: *при написании восьми неверных букв код работает верно и выходит из программы.* Потому что `break`.  *Но при написании полного слова предоставленного в массиве не завершается.* Потому что нет `break` - и соответственно `while True`.

Comment: *Как закончить программу?*... Напишите "Конец.". А если серьёзно, добавьте в свой вопрос следующее: что за программа? что она должна делать? что не получается? Среди новичков прослеживается досадная тенденция вставлять в вопрос либо код, либо описание программы, хотя нужно всегда добавлять **и код, и описание того, что он должен делать, и описание, что у Вас не получается!** Только тогда Вам смогут дать корректный полезный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если в угадываемом слове не осталось ни одной `*`, то выходим из бесконечного цикла:

```
print(''.join(gamer_word))
# добавляем условие выхода
if(all(w != '*' for w in gamer_word)):
    break
```